# Uploading Pdf to server using Retrofit 2

Tags: php, android, retrofit2

I am trying to upload Pdf files to server using **Retrofit 2.0** and store their path to my MySQL database. I am successful in storing the path but the pdf that is supposed to be stored in my home directory is corrupted.

**upload.php**

```
<?php

require "init.php";

if($con)
{
    $title=$_POST['title'];
    $pdf=$_POST['pdf'];

    //Getting the server ip
    $server_ip = gethostbyname(gethostname());

    $upload_path="uploads/$title.pdf";

    $upload_url = 'http://'.$server_ip.'/pdfupload1/'.$upload_path;

    $sql="insert into pdfinfo1(title,path) values('$title','$upload_url');";

        if(mysqli_query($con,$sql))
        {
            file_put_contents($upload_path,$pdf);

            echo json_encode(array('response'=>"Pdf Uploaded Successfully"));

        }
        else
        {
            echo json_encode(array('response'=>"Pdf Upload Failed"));

        }
        mysqli_close($con);
}
?>
```

**ApiClient.java**

```
    public class ApiClient
{

    private static final String BaseUrl="http://10.0.2.2/pdfupload1/";

    private static Retrofit retrofit;

    public static Retrofit getApiClient()
    {
        if(retrofit==null)
        {
            retrofit=new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(BaseUrl).addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }
}
```

**ApiInterface.java**

```
    public interface ApiInterface
{
    @Multipart
    @POST("upload.php")
    Call<PdfClass> PdfUploadFunction (@Part("title") RequestBody title, @Part("pdf") RequestBody image);
}
```

**PdfClass.java**

```
   public class PdfClass
{
    //This is a Model Class Retrofit

    @SerializedName("title")
    private String Title;

    @SerializedName("pdf")
    private String Pdf;

    @SerializedName("response")
    private String Response;

    public String getResponse() {
        return Response;
    }
}
```

**FilePath.java**

```
   public class FilePath {

    /**
     * Method for return file path of Gallery image
     *
     * @param context
     * @param uri
     * @return path of the selected image file from gallery
     */

    public static String getPath(final Context context, final Uri uri)
    {
        //check here to KITKAT or new version
        final boolean isKitKat = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT;

        // DocumentProvider
        if (isKitKat && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri)) {

            // ExternalStorageProvider
            if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
                final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                final String type = split[0];

                if ("primary".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
                    return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + split[1];
                }
            }

            //DownloadsProvider
            else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {

                final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                        Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), Long.valueOf(id));

                return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null);
            }

            // MediaProvider
            else if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
                final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                final String type = split[0];

                Uri contentUri = null;
                if ("image".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                } else if ("video".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                } else if ("audio".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                }

                final String selection = "_id=?";
                final String[] selectionArgs = new String[] {
                        split[1]
                };

                return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, selection, selectionArgs);
            }
        }
        // MediaStore (and general)
        else if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {

            // Return the remote address
            if (isGooglePhotosUri(uri))
                return uri.getLastPathSegment();

            return getDataColumn(context, uri, null, null);
        }
        // File
        else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
            return uri.getPath();
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Get the value of the data column for this Uri. This is useful for
     * MediaStore Uris, and other file-based ContentProviders.
     *
     * @param context The context.
     * @param uri The Uri to query.
     * @param selection (Optional) Filter used in the query.
     * @param selectionArgs (Optional) Selection arguments used in the query.
     * @return The value of the _data column, which is typically a file path.
     */
    public static String getDataColumn(Context context, Uri uri, String selection,
                                       String[] selectionArgs) {

        Cursor cursor = null;
        final String column = "_data";
        final String[] projection = {
                column
        };

        try {
            cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs,
                    null);
            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                final int index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column);
                return cursor.getString(index);
            }
        } finally {
            if (cursor != null)
                cursor.close();
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * @param uri The Uri to check.
     * @return Whether the Uri authority is ExternalStorageProvider.
     */
    public static boolean isExternalStorageDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.externalstorage.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    /**
     * @param uri The Uri to check.
     * @return Whether the Uri authority is DownloadsProvider.
     */
    public static boolean isDownloadsDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.providers.downloads.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    /**
     * @param uri The Uri to check.
     * @return Whether the Uri authority is MediaProvider.
     */
    public static boolean isMediaDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.providers.media.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    /**
     * @param uri The Uri to check.
     * @return Whether the Uri authority is Google Photos.
     */
    public static boolean isGooglePhotosUri(Uri uri) {
        return "com.google.android.apps.photos.content".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }
}
```

**FirstActivity.java**

```
  public class FirstActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button button1,button2;
    EditText imagename;
    ImageView imageView;
    private static final int PDF_REQUEST=777;
    private Bitmap bitmap;

    public int PDF_REQ_CODE = 1;

    String PdfNameHolder, PdfPathHolder, PdfID;
    Uri uri;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_first);

        button1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        button2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);

        imagename=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        //imageView=(ImageViewfindViewById(R.id.imageView1);




        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                //selectImage();
                selectPdf();


            }
        });

        button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                // uploadImage();
                PdfUploadFunction();

            }
        });

    }

    private void selectPdf()
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent();

        intent.setType("application/pdf");

        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Pdf"), PDF_REQ_CODE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == PDF_REQ_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {

            uri = data.getData();

        }
    }

    public void PdfUploadFunction() {

        PdfNameHolder = imagename.getText().toString();

        PdfPathHolder = FilePath.getPath(this, uri);

        //File file=new File(uri.getPath());




            RequestBody Title=RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"),imagename.getText().toString());
            RequestBody Pdf=RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/pdf"), PdfPathHolder);
            ApiInterface apiInterface=ApiClient.getApiClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
            Call<PdfClass> call=apiInterface.PdfUploadFunction(Title,Pdf);

            call.enqueue(new Callback<PdfClass>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<PdfClass> call, Response<PdfClass> response) {

                    PdfClass pdfClass=response.body();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Server Response: "+pdfClass.getResponse(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<PdfClass> call, Throwable t) {

                }
            });

    }

    public void AllowRunTimePermission(){

        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE))
        {

            Toast.makeText(this,"READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission Access Dialog", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } else {

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{ Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int RC, String per[], int[] Result) {

        switch (RC) {

            case 1:

                if (Result.length > 0 && Result[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    Toast.makeText(this,"Permission Granted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                } else {

                    Toast.makeText(this,"Permission Canceled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help..

Answer (score 3):

In your `PdfUploadFunction()` when attaching the file to the `RequestBody pdf` your calling the path to the file instead of the actual file.

**Edit to**

```
RequestBody Pdf=RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/pdf"), new File(PdfPathHolder))
```

And No **Thank You** for the `FilePath` class.
Needed that in for my code to work.

Also consider adding a call timeout in `Retrofit getApiClient()` because depending of file size the call might produce a `TimeOut` failure.

**Edit to**

```
public static Retrofit getApiClient(){
    if(retrofit==null){
        retrofit=new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BaseUrl)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .client(new OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
                    .connectTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .readTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .writeTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .build())
                .build();
    }
    return retrofit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its a bit late, 
but i think you
have to do changes like this

```
 String PDFPATH = FilePath.getPath(MainActivity.this,uri);
    File file = new File(PDFPATH);
    String namepdf = "newpdf";
    pdfname.setText(file.getName());


    RequestBody Title = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"),namepdf);
    RequestBody PDFreq = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/pdf"),file.getName());
    //MultipartBody.Part PDF = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("pdf",file.getName(),PDFreq);
    APIInterface apiInterface=ApiClient.getApiClient().create(APIInterface.class);
    Call<PdfClass> call=apiInterface.PdfUploadFunction(Title,PDFreq);
```

at PDFreq = add file.getname() not new file(pdfpath) it will show in ur database pdfcontains and we want pdf path and store the in our server so 
make this small change and you're good to go...